# All paths in the matrix that pass through given point

Tags: matrix, path

Can someone please help with the following interview question:

Let `a` be `MxN` matrix.
Write a function with the following prototype:

```
void PrintAllPaths(int** a, int M, int N, int x, int y) {};
```

that prints all the paths in matrix from lower left `(0,0)` to bothom right corner `(M-1,N-1)` which pass through point `(x,y)` along the way. On each step of the path one can go only right or down.
Sample:

```
PrintAllPaths (a, 3, 3, 1, 2);
```

should print:

```
(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(1,2)(2,2)
(0,0)(0,1)(1,1)(1,2)(2,2)
(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(2,2)
```

I have few ideas:

1. Find all paths from `(0,0)` to `(x,y)` and all paths from `(x,y)` to `(M-1,N-1)`. Make a Cartesian product of paths from these two somehow.
2. Use matrix `a` for backtracking. I guess it can be used since the printout of the function does not depend on data in a. Solve `(a,M,N,x,y)` by going right and recursively solving `(a,M,N-1,x,y-1)` and going down and recursively solving `(a,M-1,N,x-1,y)`.

However, I have problem to implement this. I can not keep track of the paths properly. 
Can someone help with the code (or better ideas)?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I finally managed to convert idea 2 to the working code. I didn't use matrix `a` for path backtracking, since it was not needed.
It is still fairly complicated, so if someone has more elegant solution, please post!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void PrintAllPaths(int **a, int M, int N, int x, int y) {
    static char Path[500]="(0,0)"; //keeps path for currently processed recursion
    static int m=M, n=N; //keep initial values of M and N
    static bool passedXY=false; //have we passed (x,y) along current path?

    if ((x<0 || y<0) && (passedXY==false)) { return;} //missed (X,Y), so skip
    if (x==0 && y==0) passedXY=true;

    if ((M==1 && N==1)) {puts(Path); return;};  //we have made N-1 steps down and M-1 steps right, so we reached (M-1,N-1) and we print path

    //try to go right   
    if (N>1) {
        char temp[10];
        sprintf(temp,"(%d,%d)",m-M,n-N+1); //add point to the right to the path
        strcat(Path,temp);
        PrintAllPaths(a, M, N-1, x, y-1);  //go right
        Path[strlen(Path)-5]='\0';  //remove last point from the path, since it is processed
        if ((x>0 && y>=0)||(x>=0 && y>0)) passedXY=false; //reset passedXY value if needed
    };

    //try to go down
    if (M>1) {
        char temp[10];
        sprintf(temp,"(%d,%d)",m-M+1,n-N);
        strcat(Path,temp);
        PrintAllPaths(a, M-1, N, x-1, y); 
        Path[strlen(Path)-5]='\0';
        if ((x>0 && y>=0)||(x>=0 && y>0)) passedXY=false;
    }

};


int main() {
int **a=0;
PrintAllPaths(a, 3, 3, 1, 2);
char ch='a'; scanf("%c",ch);
}
```